# How to work out the trajectories of the cannons in Mario 64

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

So recently I've played one of my childhood games again, namely Super Mario 64, and as anyone who has played it as well knows, you will find cannons at specific locations that allow Mario to send himself flying in the direction he is pointing at, even allowing him to change its **rotational angle**. Now obviously the trajectory resembles a parabola, and obviously the parabola's general shape (as in its coefficient a) depends on the cannon's angle, and (correct me if I am wrong, physicists) on how much Mario gets accelerated by the cannon. Some quick research said

Mario's mass = **90kg = m_mario**

I couldn't really come up with a velocity through research, so I am just gonna assume that

**v = 20m/s** 
v0 = 0m/s

The acceleration from firing the cannon feels rather fast, so I am gonna assume

**a = (20-v0)/ 0.3 = 66m/s².**

Therefore, **f_Cannon = 90*66 = 5940N** (just in case that's gonna be of use later on)

Now my **first question** is: I'm sure there must be a way of sort of "converting" the rotational angle and f_cannon into a correlating coefficient "a" for the parabola trajectory. I suspect trigonometric functions might be helpful, but I can't really think of a way to solve this problem.

**Question #2:** I also wondered if it would be possible to find out what "a" would have to be equal to in oder for the parabola to have a specific root apart from x = 0 (assuming b = 1 and c = 0, always).

Example: Say at **x = 7** there is a power star, and Mario wants to collect the star hovering in the air just before he hits the ground at x = 7. if the parabola = ax²+x, then it is possible to find a: f(a) = 49a+7
**a = (-7/49)**

[Here are my personal figures for solving this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYPcc.jpg)

[How to find a for the root x = 7, assuming b = 1 and c = 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHS4j.jpg)

Please excuse any mathematical errors of mine, I'm just your average freshman who likes math a lot, lol.

Thanks!

Comment: 90kg, dang Mario should take it easier with those pizzas.

Comment: @mathreadler I would be glad to have only $90kg$ ...

Comment: Although this is framed very well, and I love the references to Mario 64, this is a physics question more than anything, and you could definitely find work written about this in any Newtonian physics book. It's actually a pretty straight forward use of undergraduate physics. Mario 64 probably fudges the numbers a bit, but it's most definitely essentially your basic model of a cannon firing a cannonball (which is typically a problem on any first year physics test).

Comment: Well, the title might be a bit misleading, my question is not really how cannons work, it's more about how the parabola "changes" with respect to whatever angle you set it up in. I can't really imagine that this question ("Find the quadratic equation for an angle of 49°/87°/blahblah°) would occur on a firstr year physics test, or am I wrong about that?

Comment: I guess anything that's not very high school or college level math is not even paid any attention to on this forum.

Comment: When it occurs probably depends on your local education system. If I don't remember wrong where I'm from we had some question like that in physics when we were 17 yo. It was maybe one of the more difficult ones for the people aiming for the higher grades, but still.

Comment: This question is about physics more than mathematics. And it is a problem about the cinematics of a cannonball, so you don't need the mass of Mario at all, just the exit speed from the cannon. Depending on the angle this speed will have a component directed along $x$ and the other along $y$. Now you have a constant motion and an accelerated motion. Solve the latter to know how much time Mario is flying.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to simplify this:

- Mario leaves the cannon at the origin $(0,0)$ with a speed $V_0$ at an angle $\theta$ measured from the horizontal, so has a horizontal component of velocity of $V_0 \cos(\theta)$ and an initial vertical component of velocity of $V_0 \sin(\theta)$
- Assuming no air resistance, at time $t$ Mario will have travelled $x=V_0 \cos(\theta) t$ horizontally, and due to gravity $g$ will be at a height $y = V_0 \sin(\theta) t - \frac12 g t^2$
- In terms of $x$ we have $t = \frac{1}{V_0 \cos(\theta)}x$, and substituting gives the parabola

$$y = - \frac{g}{2V_0^2\cos^2(\theta) }x^2  +\tan(\theta) x$$

If you want this to also hit the $x$-axis at the particular point $(x_1,0)$ then that requires $\frac{g x_1}{V_0 } = 2 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta) = \sin(2\theta) $ so $$\theta = \frac12\sin^{-1} \left( \frac{g x_1}{V_0^2 }  \right)$$ being aware that there can be more than one angle with a given sine

Taking your example numbers of $V_0=20$ and $x_1=7$ together with $g=9.8$ you would get $$\theta \approx 0.0862 \text{ or } 1.4846 \text{ radians}$$ i.e. about $\theta \approx 5^\circ \text{ or } 85^\circ$, either a very shallow trajectory or a very high one.  That would give the approximate parabolas $$y\approx -0.01234 x^2 + 0.08639x$$ 
$$y\approx -1.65363 x^2 +11.57542x$$